# Getting an error while running uiautomatorviewer in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: java, android, android-studio, uiautomatorviewer

The following error is displayed when the command is executed:

username@device:~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin$ ./uiautomatorviewer

Djava.ext.dirs=/home/username/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/home/username/Android/Sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

---

then I use --class-path in uiautomatorviewer file and face this error:
I use this method for editing uiautomatorviewer file: https://www.programmersought.com/article/53371586152/

error: unable to initialize main class com.android.uiautomator.uiautomatorviewer caused by: java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/control
mychange:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH3RH.png)
original:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuMzg.png)
And when I got the above error, I turned back to the previous state

### And now I have the first issue again.

extera information:
$JAVA_HOME  =>  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

$ANDROID_HOME  =>  /home/username/Android/Sdk

Android studio version: 4.1.3

Comment: Your question is unclear.  If you used `--class-path`, the Java command won't recognize it.  If you used `-classpath` like the error message said ... please show us **exactly** what you changed the `uiautomatorviewer` script to.

Comment: Note that the `ext.dirs` mechanism wasn't removed until Java 9, so it it doubtful that you are actually *using* Java 8 to run the program.

Comment: @StephenC Hi and thanks for your time. for your second comment: I used both, but it doesn't work.
my main issue is:
Djava.ext.dirs=/home/username/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/home/username/Android/Sdk/tools/lib is not supported. Use -classpath instead. Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
I changed the file according to this link:
https://www.programmersought.com/article/53371586152/
And what can I do for solving this problem?

Comment: The solution is to either *really* use Java 8, OR use `-classpath` ... *correctly*.  I can't help you further unless you provide the information that I requested.  Please provide the information by [EDITING](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67300521/edit) the question.  Not as comments.

Comment: You still haven't done what I requested.  Please show me the changes that you made to the `uiautomatorviewer` script.  (I don't want to see the instructions that you think you followed.  I want to see the *actual* changes.)

Comment: @StephenC I added the two photos of uiautomatorviewer file. once is original another one is my changes

Comment: Sigh ... [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Add this line before the `exec` line, and show us all of the console output:  `set -x ; ${javaCmd} -version`

Comment: +java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
+exec java -Xmx1600M -Djava.ext.dirs=/home/alielyasi/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/home/alielyasi/Android/Sdk/tools/lib -Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=/home/alielyasi/Android/Sdk/tools -jar /home/alielyasi/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/uiautomatorviewer-26.0.0-dev.jar-Djava.ext.dirs=/home/alielyasi/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/home/alielyasi/Android/Sdk/tools/lib is not supported.Useclasspath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the output that I asked for in the comments.

```
+java -version 
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing) 
+exec java -Xmx1600M -Djava.ext.dirs=/home/alielyasi/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/home/alielyasi/Android/Sdk/tools/lib -Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=/home/alielyasi/Android/Sdk/tools -jar /home/alielyasi/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/uiautomatorviewer-26.0.0-dev.jar
-Djava.ext.dirs=/home/alielyasi/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/home/alielyasi/Android/Sdk/tools/lib is not supported.
Use -classpath
```

Firstly, we can see that the Java command that is being used is `java`, not a specific (absolute) pathname.

That is OK, but it means that `$PATH` will be used to resolve `java` to the actaul pathname of a Java launcher.  (Not `$JAVA_HOME`.)

Second, we can see that `java -version` is telling us that it is using Java 11.0.11.  As I mentioned in my comments, Java 9 and later do not support the "ext.dirs" mechanism.

Unfortunately, the `java` command's suggestion to use `-classpath` is not going to work (as-is).

So I am going to give you two ways to solve this:

### Solution #1: Just use Java 8.

You need to make sure that you have Java 8 installed, and that running the `java -version` prints out that that the version number is `8.0.xxx`, where `xxx` is (ideally) the latest available Java 8 patch release.

Since you are using using Ubuntu 20.04, there are two ways to make sure that you are using Java 8 rather than Java 11.

- You could make Java 8 the default Java version *globally* using the "alternatives" system.  Run `man update-alternatives` for the documentation.  (You need to run `update-alternatives` as root ...)
- You could make Java 8 the default for the current user or the current shell by changing the `PATH` environment variable.

### Solution #2: Adjust the script so that Java 11 will work.

As I said above, simply converting `-Djava.ext.dirs=...` into a `-classpath` option doesn't work.  That is because the `exec` line is using the `-jar` option, and when `-jar` is used `-classpath` is ignored.  But `-jar` means this is an "executable JAR", and the entrypoint class name is coming from the JAR file's manifest.

So we need to unpick this.

First we need to know what the (full) entrypoint class name is, and also JAR file is setting its own classpath.  We can determine by using the `jar` command to extract the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file and looking it.

Next we need to form a classpath consisting of

- the path that is currently given by `$frameworkdir`
- the path for the main JAR file (i.e. `$jarpath`)
- the path specified in the manifest file

The order of the path *could be significant*.

The entire classpath needs to be given to the `java` command via a `-classpath` or `-cp` option.  (Not `--class-path`.)

Finally remove `-jar $jarpath` and replace it with the full entrypoint class name.  (It is a class name, not a pathname.  Don't change the dots to slashes, add a suffix or do anything like that. Use the name exactly as the manifest file gives it.)

This approach *should* work, but I can't test it.  If it fails, please comment below.

Comment: Yes , it works for me. I just switch to java version 8 on Ubuntu and uiautomator works.